Async js script cannot inject another js script sometimes
I have a parent js script which is inserted into an article page. The way it's getting injected is like this:
<script async src="https://example.com/parent.js"></script>

I have versioning as well. When the parent script is executed, It checks the Browser's local storage. If a key (version) is found, It will use that version otherwise it will send a request to an API and gets the latest version and stores it into the local storage.

Now when the version is found either by API or Local storage, It construct another js script and injects it into the page:
<script src="https://example.com/version/child.js"></script>

In the articles which the parent.js is injected into the , There's no problem.

However in one article, The parent.js is injected in the middle of the body.

On the first load, It sends a request to the API and gets the latest version and injects the child.js into the head. Everything works fine.

But on the second load when it reads the version from child.js and injects it into the head, I check the DOM using the inspect and I can't find the child.js !!

However the console logs indicate that the child.js is running but it's not in the DOM. I can even find the child.js inside the Sources tab of the developer tools.

I guess I have a timing issue which when the API request is sent, Enough time has spent and everything will work fine. But when it reads the version from local storage, This issue appears.

Also when I toggle the Disabled Cache inside the Network tab, It helps the issue but it's not always consistent.

Thank you for your help in advance!

There is no question inside your text, so it's hard to answer. While reading your question I wondered why not just save function from child.js into window.mycoolscript to be able to access and/or check for it existance it without DOM? But I don't know if thats what you are asking about because there is no question...

Thanks for your comment. My question is that why I am seeing this behavior in the browser? Funny enough, The child.js is running (because I can see the console logs of it) but its 
Well, thats because they are just different things: DOM is representation of visual widgets of the page. While js script isn't visual. For example you can just use eval somewhere in scripts to create any other scripts to run. This won't touch DOM at all, but the scripts will run. Also js script might have different life span, for example if a timer was used from it - it continues to run.

I see. But first of all, The parent.js is inside the DOM. and also after I fetched the version, I am injecting the script using this code: document.head.append(scriptElement); Now this sometimes work (which the child.js script element is inside the head) and sometimes doesn't but in both cases the script is running!

That might be issue of the script and timing, cant tell exactly without seeing and debugging the code. Likely something like this: 1. the script loads and is added to the DOM, 2. the script starts and runs, 3. some othe part of script manipulates DOM and replaces that node where the script was, but this won't kill running instance of the script. Part 3 may take place if the script loads twice because as you mentioned: you manipulate DOM on each load, so the second one can delete DOM node that loaded before. And because this won't affect scripts runtime you get surprized.

you know what's better than a wall of words when asking for help with code? Actual code that demonstrates the issue you have

I think we are getting close. No manipulation is done through the parent.js except it injects the child.js inside the . I have added a 300ms delay before injecting the child.js inside the . It helped the issue a lot. Also I have added a code to make sure the ready state is "complete" or "interactive". It did also help. But 1 out of 20 loads, I see the issue again @YuriYaryshev
